# python3 os write, end file

Tags: python-3.x, file, file-writing

I have am trying to open a file for writing and I am using os.write() because I need to lock my files. I don't know how to write a string to the file and have the remaining file content removed. For example, the code below first writes `qwertyui` to the file, and then writes `asdf` to the file, which results in the file containing `asdftyui`. I would like to know how I can do this so that the resulting content of the file is `asdf`.

```
import os

fileName = 'file.txt'

def write(newContent):
    fd = os.open(fileName,os.O_WRONLY|os.O_EXLOCK)
    os.write(fd,str.encode(newContent))
    os.close(fd)

write('qwertyui')
write('asdf')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `os.O_TRUNC` to the flags:

```
os.open(fileName,os.O_WRONLY|os.O_EXLOCK|os.O_TRUNC)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

fileName = 'file.txt'

def write(newContent):
    fd = os.open(fileName,os.O_WRONLY|os.O_EXLOCK)
    Lastvalue = os.read(fd, os.path.getsize(fd))
    os.write(fd,str.encode(Lastvalue.decode() +newContent))
    os.close(fd)

write('qwertyui')
write('asdf')
```

Comment: The OP does not want to save the previous contents.